# Django module not retrieving data from API

Tags: django, url, django-rest-framework

I have a class  that I call from my project that is executed through the url: data/refresh

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
from rest_framework import routers


router = routers.DefaultRouter()

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^refresh/$', views.refresh),
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls', namespace='rest_framework')),

]
```

and my **views.py**

```
def refresh(request):
    gatorate = Gatorate()
    r = gatorate.start()
    if r["code"] < 0:
        return {"code":-1,"error":r["error"]}
    # while spider.has_next_page() == True:
    data = gatorate.run()

    # #run last page
    # spider.run()

    return JsonResponse({"code":1,"data":data}
```

The class runs and populates my database when I run in Development, and in production it works ONLY if I start python, import my module, and execute it from ssh on the server.
However when I open its url, or use a button that executes the URL, I get 502 error, or, I dont get an error, and it just does not populate.
 I am wondering if there is a permission issue that is not allowing me to run the script, or the fact that it does not enter the virtual environment if that even makes sense.  Also, if anyone can suggest a way to automate this to run everyday, I was planning on using CRON, but I like the flexibility to execute it from the url remotely maybe using a lambda to call it. I have everything already on aws EC2 to my RDS both inside a VPC.  Most important I just want the thing to work. THANK YOU IN ADVANCED.

**spider.spider.py:**

```
import sqlite3
import MySQLdb
import time
import os
import django
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = 'web.settings'
django.setup()
from django.utils import timezone
from webservice.models import BSR
from vardata import ASINS

class Gatorate:

    def __init__(self):
        self.amazon = None
        self.product = None
        self.asins = None
        self.ASINS = ASINS

    def start(self):
        #options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        #options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
        #options.add_argument('headless')
        #self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
        #self.driver.get(self.url)

        try:
            self.amazon = AmazonAPI(AMAZON_ACCESS_KEY, AMAZON_SECRET_KEY, AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG,region="US")
            # options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            # options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable'
            # # options.add_argument('headless')
            # self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
            # #wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, self.sleep)
            # self.driver.get(self.url)
            return {"code":1}

        except Exception as e  :
            #self.driver.quit()
            return {"code":-1,"error": str(e)}

    def get_asins(self):
        try:
            asins = self.ASINS

            return {"code":1,"data":asins}

        except Exception as e:
            #print e

            return {"code":-2,"error":e}



    def refresh_asins(self,asins):
        """Extracts cars from page

        @scope: 
        @param: list
        @return list"""
        extract = []#list to hold the extracted data
        print asins
        if asins is None:
            return{"code":-1,"error":"Not defined"}

        if len(asins) == 0:
            return {"code":-2,"error":"Empty value"}
        for asin in set(asins):
            print 'finding sku: '+ str(asin)
            try:
                #by ASIN or BY SKU choose one
                time.sleep(1)
                self.product = self.amazon.lookup(ItemId=asin)
                # SKU
                # self.product = self.amazon.lookup(ItemId=sku, IdType="SKU",SearchIndex='All')

                print str(self.product)

                try:
                    ASIN = asin
                except Exception as e:
                    ASIN = "N/A"
                    print e
                try:
                    Brand = self.product.get_attribute("Brand")

                except Exception as e:
                    Brand = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    selling_price = self.product.price_and_currency
                    selling_price = selling_price[0]

                except Exception as e:
                    price = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    currency = self.product.price_and_currency
                    currency = currency[1]
                except Exception as e:
                    price = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    availability = self.product.availability

                except Exception as e:
                    availability = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    sales_rank = self.product.sales_rank
                except Exception as e:
                    sales_rank = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    Binding = self.product.get_attribute("Binding")
                    time.sleep(5)
                except Exception as e:
                    Binding = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    Color = self.product.get_attribute("Color")
                    time.sleep(5)
                except Exception as e:
                    Color = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    Title = self.product.get_attribute("Title")
                    time.sleep(5)
                except Exception as e:
                    Title = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    PackageQuantity = self.product.get_attribute("PackageQuantity")
                    time.sleep(5)
                except Exception as e:
                    PackageQuantity = ""
                    print e
                try:
                    ProductGroup = self.product.get_attribute("ProductGroup")
                    time.sleep(5)
                except Exception as e:
                    ProductGroup = ""
                    print e

                c = BSR(
                    ASIN=asin,
                    Brand=Brand,
                    Selling_Price=selling_price,
                    Currency=currency,
                    Availability=availability,
                    BSR=sales_rank,
                    Binding=Binding,
                    Color=Color,
                    Product_Description=Title,
                    Package_Quantity=PackageQuantity,
                    Product_Group=ProductGroup
                    ).save()
            except Exception as e:
                print e


    def run(self):
        """ Run me"""
        r = self.get_asins()
        if r["code"] < 0:
            return {"code":-1,"error":r["error"]}
        print r["data"]
        time.sleep(5)
        r = self.refresh_asins(r["data"])
        time.sleep(5)
        # print "this is what we are saving"+str(r)
        # r = self.save_skus(r)
        # if self.has_next_page():
        #   self.go_to_next_page()
        return {"code":1,"data":"complete"}
```

Comment: .  So far I just made a project, added one app to it called webservice. Inside I have the model, and view that triggers the script to execute in spider.py. I made my migrations and the table is there. Then I have a url data/refresh/ that will call my Gatorate class, that runs the script. I am not sure about the layout. You can recreate it by running a skeleton django project, and adding 1 model, and 1 module spider.py. Then modifying the urls to trigger the view, and then the view has the refresh class to execute the spider.run() command.

Answer (score 0):

It will serve you best to expose the refresh operation as a [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/) and schedule a cron job for it.

Long running operations like what you're doing here either results in a 502 or 504 http error depending on how your server handles it.

Answer (score 0):

SO it turns out that since I am running a virtual enviroment, I simply had to activate my python, and my virtualevn so that the command would work. Also the command was taking too long and that is why I got the 502 since it was timing out. The script takes about 5 minutes to run. So now with the crontab I have it activating the virtualenv and running the command. Last in order to make sure I have a button on the site to refresh, I have a second cron checking for a value in the database that is set to false. If a user clicks the button, it changes that value in the db to True. The next time my cron job check if the value is true, it will then execute the refresh.